# Regexp for validating decimals not working

Tags: javascript

I have a form that has a field that takes what a decimal value.  The desired requirements for this decimal are that it be in the form ##.## with two numbers on each side of the decimal point.

I found a regex online that is supposed to validate the decimal, but instead views any input as invalid. Here is the code I have:

```
function validateDecimal(number)
{
eval("var stringvar=/^[-+]?([0-9]*\\.[0-9]{0,2})|([0-9]+)$/");

return stringvar.test(number);
}
```

And the call...

```
var numStr = document.getElementById('Amount');
if (!validateDecimal(numStr)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid dollar amount in the form ##.##");
    return false;
}
```

I understand that this regex is not exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to figure out why it views all input as invalid.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `document.getElementById('Amount').value` maybe ?? Also why `eval`?

Comment: @elclanrs that was exactly it. Can't believe I didn't notice that. I think I just stared at it for so long that I never really looked for such a simple fix.

Comment: OK, let me craft an answer for you, I'll point out the other problems too...

Comment: ... in other words, learn to do some basic debugging.  Learning a few simple tricks with Firebug will save you a **ton** of time chasing down things like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is that you forgot to grab the actual value of your input:

```
document.getElementById('Amount').value
```

The second problem is `eval`, you don't need it here, you can write it like this:

```
var stringvar = /^[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]{0,2})|([0-9]+)$/;
```

And third, here's the regex I propose if your number must *always* be `XX.XX`:

```
/^[+-]?\d\d\.\d\d$/
```

Answer (score 0):

first off, you shouldn't be using eval like that, it puts unnecessary stress on the client, just do

```
var regex = /^[-+]?([0-9]*\\.[0-9]{0,2})|([0-9]+)$/;
return regex.test(number);
```

instead.

And you need to use `.value` after `getElementById('Amount');`